Blender Edge Loop Select Not Working
Machine Specs:
Version:   Blender 4.2.0
OS:        Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics × 6
GPU:       Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne
Using trackpad.
Issue:
I cannot get Edge Loop Select to work at all.  I've tried multiple combinations of Alt/Ctrl/Shift + Left Mouse Button/Right Mouse Button/Middle Mouse Button, and nothing works.
I do not have Emulate 3 Button Mouse selected.  My trackpad has 3 buttons and has worked fine so far.
But, when I press Alt + Left Mouse Button a 4-pointed arrow icon appears (similar to a compass showing the 4 directions). If I move with this icon displayed, it will un-maximize the program, (i.e., it does not minimize it to the taskbar, but makes it a smaller size on the screen). This behavior occurs with all programs, so there may be some systems app interfering with Blender?

If you wind up answering your own question you're allowed to post your own discovery as the official answer. We're all just trying to get each question to be answered, one way or another. Doesn't matter who answers ultimately. You might have to get a bit more rep to answer question since you're new but whenever you can just do that.

Thank you  @Jakemoyo

The process of writing out the problem led me to the answer: the window manager was interfering with Blender. Since I've spent about 2 hours trying to fix this problem, I'll post this in case someone else has the same problem. Here are the steps to solve it:
(Note: I'm using Linux Mint.  An MS Widows machine will be a little different.)
App menu button (same as the Windows Start button),> System Settings > Windows, (there are 3 tabs at the top: Titlebar, Behavior, Alt-Tab) > Behavior (at the bottom) Special Key to move and resize windows, change to Disabled (or something other than Alt).


You do not have to write "SOLVED" on top of your answer. If it would not (supposedly) solve the problem there would be no point in posting it in the first place, right?  ;)

I guess this is related to Blender, though kind of niche. I'd call it more general computer usage problems, but I'll leave it open. Also, "The process of writing out the problem led me to the answer," has happened to me many times, lol. There's even a name for it in software development; rubber-duck programming. Just the mental gear switch of explaining something helps you get it way better, problem or no problem.

It is related to Blender.  Though the solution was in my machine's general setup, it was preventing Blender from functioning.  It took me hours to find a solution because none of the other posts with similar problems had this issue.
